# Combine unnormalized key/value columns into normalized form

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a legacy database with a table that looks like this:

| Account | Key1 | Key2 | Key3 | Val1 | Val2 | Val3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Home | Work |  | 555-555-1111 | 555-555-2222 |  |
| 2 | Home |  |  | 555-555-3333 |  |  |
| 3 | Mobile | Work | Home | 555-555-4444 | 555-555-5555 | 555-555-6666 |

I'd like to transform that into a properly normalized form in Pandas. The desired output looks like this:

| Account | PhoneType | PhoneNumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Home | 555-555-1111 |
| 1 | Work | 555-555-2222 |
| 2 | Home | 555-555-3333 |
| 3 | Mobile | 555-555-4444 |
| 3 | Work | 555-555-5555 |
| 3 | Home | 555-555-6666 |

The following code will create a dataframe to start with:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {
        "Account": "1",
        "Key1": "Home",
        "Key2": "Work",
        "Val1": "555-555-1111",
        "Val2": "555-555-2222"
    },
    {
        "Account": "2",
        "Key1": "Home",
        "Val1": "555-555-3333"
    },
    {
        "Account": "3",
        "Key1": "Mobile",
        "Key2": "Work",
        "Key3": "Home",
        "Val1": "555-555-4444",
        "Val2": "555-555-5555",
        "Val3": "555-555-6666"
    }
])
```

What's the cleanest / most efficient way to transform the dataframe as indicated above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [wide-to-long](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) for this

```
(
    pd.wide_to_long(df,
                ['Key','Val'],
                i='Account', j='n')
      .dropna()
      .reset_index()
      .drop(columns='n')
      .sort_values(by='Account')
)
```

Output

```
 Account     Key           Val
0       1    Home  555-555-1111
3       1    Work  555-555-2222
1       2    Home  555-555-3333
2       3  Mobile  555-555-4444
4       3    Work  555-555-5555
5       3    Home  555-555-6666
```

Edit: You could achieve this w/melt and lookup, but since [lookup is deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#looking-up-values-by-index-column-labels) it takes a little more effort.

```
import numpy as np
x = df.melt(id_vars=['Account','Key1','Key2','Key3'],
            var_name='PhoneType',
            value_name='PhoneNumber')

# This used to be what the lookup method in pandas did prior to being depricated
idx, cols =  pd.factorize(x['PhoneType'].str.replace('Val','Key'))
x['PhoneType']  = x.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(x)), idx]


x[['Account','PhoneType','PhoneNumber']].dropna().sort_values(by='Account')
```

Comment: Elegant solution. Is there any way to do this with `pd.melt`?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR In theory I believe so, since wide_to_long is basically a modified version of melt, but there's no simple way to communicate that they key/val pairs should be grouped together.

Comment: Yes that's also what I thought. I read the documentations and it says `wide_to_long` is a less flexible version of `pd.melt` but still I don't think this can be achieved with just one melting operations maybe two! Thank you very much again :)

Comment: @AnoushiravanR I added the best I could come up w/melt

Comment: `wide_to_long` is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would do the transformation before moving to pandas.  Many transforms like this seem more straightforward outside of pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    {
        "Account": "1",
        "Key1": "Home",
        "Key2": "Work",
        "Val1": "555-555-1111",
        "Val2": "555-555-2222"
    },
    {
        "Account": "2",
        "Key1": "Home",
        "Val1": "555-555-3333"
    },
    {
        "Account": "3",
        "Key1": "Mobile",
        "Key2": "Work",
        "Key3": "Home",
        "Val1": "555-555-4444",
        "Val2": "555-555-5555",
        "Val3": "555-555-6666"
    }
]

rows = []
for row in data:
    for n in "123":
        if f"Key{n}" in row:
            rows.append((row['Account'],row[f'Key{n}'],row[f'Val{n}']))

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=["Account","PhoneType","PhoneNumber"])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Account PhoneType   PhoneNumber
0       1      Home  555-555-1111
1       1      Work  555-555-2222
2       2      Home  555-555-3333
3       3    Mobile  555-555-4444
4       3      Work  555-555-5555
5       3      Home  555-555-6666
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
df
    Account Key1    Key2    Val1            Val2            Key3    Val3
0   1       Home    Work    555-555-1111    555-555-2222    NaN     NaN
1   2       Home    NaN     555-555-3333    NaN             NaN     NaN
2   3       Mobile  Work    555-555-4444    555-555-5555    Home    555-555-6666

df['home_phone']   = np.select([df['Key1'].eq('Home'),df['Key2'].eq('Home'),df['Key3'].eq('Home')], [df['Val1'], df['Val2'], df['Val3']], None)
df['work_phone']   = np.select([df['Key1'].eq('Work'),df['Key2'].eq('Work'),df['Key3'].eq('Work')], [df['Val1'], df['Val2'], df['Val3']], None)
df['mobile_phone'] = np.select([df['Key1'].eq('Mobile'),df['Key2'].eq('Mobile'),df['Key3'].eq('Mobile')], [df['Val1'], df['Val2'], df['Val3']], None)
df = df.drop(columns=['Key1', 'Key2', 'Val1', 'Val2', 'Key3', 'Val3',])

df

    Account home_phone      work_phone      mobile_phone
0   1       555-555-1111    555-555-2222    None
1   2       555-555-3333    None            None
2   3       555-555-6666    555-555-5555    555-555-4444
```